# Reconstruct array javascript index-based

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, logic

suppose I have an array in JavaScript as written below :

```
Array:[  
    ["0", "Grape"],["0", "Orange"],["1", "Mango"],["2", "Strawberry"],
    ["2", "Banana"],["3", "Watermelon"]
]
```

that I want to reconstruct as :

```
Array:[  
    ["Grape", "Orange"],["Mango"],["Strawberry", "Banana"],["Watermelon"]
]
```

The numbers in initial array acts as indexes of fruits' data in reconstructed array. So, Grape and Orange are placed in index 0, Mango in index 1, and so on. How do I achieved this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a is your initial array:
Here I supposed that indices start at 0, are integers and are sorted.

```
a = [["0", "Grape"],["0", "Orange"],["1", "Mango"],["2", "Strawberry"],["2", "Banana"],["3", "Watermelon"]]
b=[];
for (i in a) {
    if (a[i][0] >= b.length)
        b.push([]);

    (b[b.length-1]).push(a[i][1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Using `reduce`, we are creating the resultant `array` where for each entry in original array, we are adding / updating the value for an index (`c[0]`).

```js
let arr1 = [["0", "Grape"],["0", "Orange"],["1", "Mango"],["2", "Strawberry"],["2", "Banana"],["3", "Watermelon"]];

let arr2 = arr1.reduce((a,c) => Object.assign(a, {[c[0]]:(a[c[0]] || []).concat(c[1])}), []);
console.log(arr2);
```